# How to filter an object by data from array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, filter

I have an array

```
const newChecked = ["recreational", "charity"]
```

and an object

```
const allActivities = [
  {activity: '...', type: 'social', },
  {activity: '...', type: 'social', },
  {activity: '...', type: 'charity', },
  {activity: '...', type: 'recreational', },
]
```

And I want to get a new object, that does not contain type that are contains in **newChecked**. In other words, `newActivitiesList` should contain data with `type` of `"social"`.

```
const newActivitiesList = allActivities.filter((item) =>
  newChecked.map((i) => {
    return item.type !== i;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const newChecked = ["recreational", "charity"]
const allActivities = [
{activity: '...', type: 'social', },
{activity: '...', type: 'social', },
{activity: '...', type: 'charity', },
{activity: '...', type: 'recreational', },
];
const res = allActivities.filter(({type})=>!newChecked.includes(type));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` function to create a new array

```js
const newChecked = ["recreational", "charity"]

const allActivities = [
  {activity: '...', type: 'social', },
  {activity: '...', type: 'social', },
  {activity: '...', type: 'charity', },
  {activity: '...', type: 'recreational', },
];

const newActivitiesList = allActivities.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if(newChecked.indexOf(current.type) === -1) {
    return accumulator.concat(current);
  } else {
    return accumulator;
  }
},[]);

console.log(newActivitiesList);
```